# Understanding Python's `importlib.reload`

Tags: python, python-importlib

I'm trying to understand how the importlib.reload method actually behaves.
I'll give a boiled down example

```py
import importlib
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import gc

def write_dummy_class(return_value):
    target = Path(__file__).parent / 'test_reload_import.py'
    target.write_text(
        "class Dummy:\n"
        f"    var = {return_value}\n"
        "    def run(self):\n"
        "        print(f'Dummy.run(self) >> self.var = {id(self.var):x}')\n"
        f"        return self.var\n"
    )

write_dummy_class(1)

from test_reload_import import Dummy

print(f'id Dummy: {id(Dummy):x}')
print(Dummy.run)
assert Dummy().run() == 1, "Initial one failed??"

write_dummy_class(2)

old_module = sys.modules["test_reload_import"]
old_dummy = old_module.Dummy  # Keep a reference alive
print(f'Reloading, old module: {id(old_module):x}')
new_module = importlib.reload(old_module)
print(f'Reloaded, new module: {id(new_module):x}')

print(f'id new Dummy: {id(new_module.Dummy):x}')
print(f'id old Dummy: {id(old_dummy):x}')

print(f'id Dummy: {id(new_module.Dummy):x}')
print(new_module.Dummy.run)
new_run = new_module.Dummy().run()
assert new_run == 2, f'Dummy.run() returned {new_run} instead of 2.'
```

This is the output:

```
id Dummy: 1dd320c0fa0
<function Dummy.run at 0x000001DD325CC700>
Dummy.run(self) >> self.var = 1dd31d06930
Reloading, old module: 1dd325c7950
Reloaded, new module: 1dd325c7950
id new Dummy: 1dd320c30d0
id old Dummy: 1dd320c0fa0
<function Dummy.run at 0x000001DD325CC790>
Dummy.run(self) >> self.var = 1dd31d06930
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_reload.py", line 240, in <module>
    assert new_run == 2, f'Dummy.run() returned {new_run} instead of 2.'
AssertionError: Dummy.run() returned 1 instead of 2.
```

Observations:

1. reloading a module returns the same memory address as the previous one for the module.
2. objects do get reloaded inside the module (`Dummy` class has another id).
3. But what is baffling to me is that the memory address of the class variable 'Dummy.var' still points to the OLD one.

Could someone explains this last bit to me? How is it that the class is re-loaded, but the class variables are not? Isn't the code re-interpreted? And as such, the `var` should be re-interpreted as well, no? So basically getting another memory address?

Which leads me to my next question: what is also not reloaded?

BTW, I know that small integers are mapped to the same memory addresses in Python. That is not what is at play here. As I'm changing a class variable from a 1 to a 2, it should be another memory address. Or if it's would be the same address, it should have a different value.

But after reloading the class, the memory address of the class variable isn't updated somehow, which baffles me. And which leads me to wonder what other objects are exhibiting the same behavior.

(Python version: 3.9.9)

Oh, and one very strange thing is that this script works perfectly fine when running under "Debug" in PyCharm. But when "Run"... It breaks at the 2nd assert.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks @DavisHerring, I initially added this little-integer-bit in my explanation, but removed it as I thought it'd be obvious to the person knowing "importlib.reload" that intimately ;-). I re-added it now. So sadly no, this is not what is at play here.

Comment: Something weird is going on here. I feel like there's probably some dumb thing I'm overlooking, but I don't know what.

Comment: You can completely eliminate the class, by the way. Simply writing `f'var = {return_value}'` demonstrates the problem - `var` isn't updated after reloading.

Comment: I think there's an actual importlib bug here. It looks like importlib isn't fetching the new source code if the file length hasn't changed.

Comment: @StevenVanIngelgem: Sorry for the misinterpretation: I saw two small integers with the same address and didn’t stop to think that they had different values (and thus couldn’t share an address even if they did have disjoint lifetimes!).

Comment: @DavisHerring: it just meant my explanation wasn't up to par :-). Thanks for pointing that out for me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an import system bug, [Python issue 31772](https://bugs.python.org/issue31772). If a source file is updated quickly without changing the file length, the import system won't realize that it's changed.

Your `importlib.reload` call is reexecuting stale bytecode instead of rereading the file. That's why `var` isn't updated to the new value - the import system is using the old bytecode for the `var = 1` version of the file.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I changed the writing into var by something else 'foo' & 'foobar'. And it did update correctly now. What a tricky bug this is!